# Unable to figure out the "undefined" in my logic

Tags: angular, logic

I am creating a statement where i insert the values based on the input from drop-down. And i am able to create a statement. But when i merge the statement snippets, i get "undefined" in the beginning and in between. What and Why is this "undefined" , i am unable to determine. Please help.
The coding is in angular2, but i believe it is simply a logic issue.

Logic -
code -

**app.component.ts**

```
// For arranging a unit and number of commas.
      for (var i = 0; i < this.subNodeItemLength; i++) {

        this.unit[i] = ", ( " + this.letter[i] + ":" + this.subnodeSelectItemtext[i] + " ) - [" + this.letter[i + 1] + " ] - ( " +
          this.letter[i + 2] + ") ";

        this.units.push(this.unit[i]);
        console.log("units = ", this.units);
        this.commas.push(this.comma);
        console.log("commas", this.commas);
        console.log("comma =", this.comma);
      }

      // Complete Statement

      for (var i = 0; i < this.subNodeItemLength; i++) {

        console.log("before statement logic = ", this.statement)


        this.statement[i] += (this.units[i] + this.commas[i - 1]);


        console.log("After logic, statement =", this.statement[i]);
      }
      console.log("final statement =", this.statement);

      // After RETURN 

      for (var i = 0; i < this.subNodeItemLength; i++) {

        this.afterReturn += this.letter[i] + this.commas[i - 1];
      }

      // Cypher Query

      this.cypherQuery = "MATCH (xab:" + this.rootItemText + " ) OPTIONAL MATCH (xab: " + this.rootItemText + ")-[r1]-(p1)" +
        this.statement + "RETURN xab,r1,p1 ," + this.afterReturn;
```

**output -**

```
units =  [", ( a:SMS ) - [b ] - ( c) "]

commas [","]

 comma = ,

units =  (2) [", ( a:SMS ) - [b ] - ( c) ", ", ( b:Collection ) - [c ] 
- ( d) "]

 commas (2) [",", ","]

comma = ,

 units =  (3) [", ( a:SMS ) - [b ] - ( c) ", ", ( b:Collection ) - [c 
  ] - ( d) ", ", ( c:Payments ) - [d ] - ( e) "]

 commas (3) [",", ",", ","]

 comma = ,

 before statement logic =  []

 After logic, statement = undefined, ( a:SMS ) - [b ] - ( c) undefined



before statement logic =  ["undefined, ( a:SMS ) - [b ] - ( c) undefined"]

After logic, statement = undefined, ( b:Collection ) - [c ] - ( d) ,

before statement logic =  (2) ["undefined, ( a:SMS ) - [b ] - ( c) undefined", "undefined, ( b:Collection ) - [c ] - ( d) ,"]

After logic, statement = undefined, ( c:Payments ) - [d ] - ( e) ,

 final statement = (3) ["undefined, ( a:SMS ) - [b ] - ( c) undefined", "undefined, ( b:Collection ) - [c ] - ( d) ,", "undefined, ( c:Payments ) - [d ] - ( e) ,"]



 NeoVis {_config: {…}, _encrypted: "ENCRYPTION_OFF", _trust: "TRUST_ALL_CERTIFICATES", _driver: Driver, 

_query: 
"MATCH (xab:Century ) OPTIONAL MATCH (xab: Century)…- ( e) ,RETURN xab,r1,p1 ,undefinedaundefinedb,c,", …}


    neovis.js:36680 Error: Invalid input 'd': expected 'w/W' or 'i/I' (line 1, column 63 (offset: 62))

    "MATCH (xab:Century ) OPTIONAL MATCH (xab: Century)-[r1]-(p1)undefined, ( a:SMS ) - [b ] - ( c) undefined,undefined, ( b:Collection ) - [c ] - ( d) ,,undefined, ( c:Payments ) - [d ] - ( e) ,RETURN xab,r1,p1 ,undefinedaundefinedb,c,"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second and third for loops you start the index at 0, so the first time through the loop, i === 0.  However, then you try and get a value for `this.commas[i - 1]`.  Since i === 0 this means you are trying to find a value for `this.commas[-1]` which will be undefined.